# Twitter Bot with Ruby in Ubuntu error installing modules python on dreamhost

Tags: python, twitter, python-2.7, dreamhost

I follow instruction like link below
withpython.com/blog/2012/03/25/how-to-code-a-twitter-bot-in-python-on-dreamhost/

but when try to Installing Modules to Python on Dreamhost, I have some problem,
when I use code below, it's working:

```
wget http://python-twitter.googlecode.com/files/python-twitter-0.8.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf python-twitter-0.8.2.tar.gz
cd python-twitter-0.8.2/
```

but when I enter code like below:

```
/home/tarlusah/local/python setup.py install --home=~/local
```

*tarlusah is my username in ubuntu and
I have error like below:

```
tarlusah@tarlusah-HP-430-Notebook-PC:~/python-twitter-0.8.2$  /home/tarlusah/local/python setup.py install --home=~/local
bash: /home/tarlusah/local/python: No such file or directory
```

Comment: try : `$ python setup.py install --home=~/local`

Comment: it's not working too :(

tarlusah@tarlusah-HP-430-Notebook-PC:~/python-twitter-0.8.2$ sudo python setup.py install --home=~/local
[sudo] password for tarlusah: 
running install
Checking .pth file support in /home/tarlusah/local/lib/python/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /home/tarlusah/local/lib/python/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH



    /home/tarlusah/local/lib/python/